# Test if number meets xxx.xx pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write validation for a field, and a regex seems like the right solution. But I can't seem to get the syntax right. Here are the basic rules

1. Must be positive
2. Up to 3 digits before the decimal
3. Up to 2 digits after the decimal
4. Decimal is only present if there are numbers following it
5. Not required to put a leading number before the decimal

This is what I came up with but it doesn't seem to be working, but I admit regex isn't my forte.

```
^[0-9]{0,3}?(\.)[0-9]{0,2}$|$
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working?". False positives, false negatives or not working completely (e.g. exceptions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `?` placement is in the wrong place. `{a,b}?` will match the least amount possible between `a` and `b`. You probably want:

`^([0-9]{0,3})(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`

Comment: `[0-9]{0,3}` means digit zero to three times. No need for `?` at all, if I'm not mistaking :)

Comment: @J0HN, Yes but as the OP said, `.12` _is_ allowed so the first part should be optional

Comment: @sshashank124 I think J0HN's point is that it's already "optional" `''.match(/[0-9]{0,3}/); // [""]`

Comment: Doesn't *any digit zero times period one two* equal to `.12`? :)

Comment: @J0HN, I'm terribly sorry. You're right. I get you know. My fault. Thank you

Comment: Doesn't this match an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

`^[0-9]{0,3}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`

This one should do what you want.

http://regex101.com/r/aX7aU7

Answer (score 0):

use this regex :

```
^(\d{0,3}|\d{0,3}\.\d{1,2})$
```

this will work according to your requirement

Comment: `{1,3}` in the first alternation else you'll also match an empty string like the other answer.

Comment: @devnull you are right sir, but I just followed what the op has written : `Up to 3 digits before the decimal`. `Upto` can take zero also

Comment: I _assume_ that would be the case when a number consists of only the decimal part.  The OP would know better, of course.